# GEO Datasets in Orange

Tags: python, orange

I am a new user to the Orange Data Mining and I was taking the BioInformatics tutorial as a means to do some initial exploring on the platform.

Going directly to the problem at hand when I put the GEO Datasets widget into my Canvas I apparently get an error downloading the datasets that is described as the following Python errors :

> ValueError                                    Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\orange_bioinformatics-2.6.1-py2.7.egg\orangecontrib\bio\widgets\OWGEODatasets.py",
>   line 518, in _on_dataready
>       data = self._datatask.result()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\OWConcurrent.py",
>   line 315, in result
>       return self._future.result(timeout)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\OWConcurrent.py",
>   line 432, in result
>       return self._get_result()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\OWConcurrent.py",
>   line 420, in _get_result
>       raise self._exception ValueError: Invalid mode ('rtb')

I have tried to find solutions online to no end and because of this I have not been able to advance with my Orange exploration. I have to clarify I'm not familiar with Python to understand what exactly those errors mean and how to fix them.

Comment: That is an error in Orange Bioinformatics add-on. A fix is already in the [pipeline](https://github.com/biolab/orange-bio/pull/26).

Answer (score 0):

Update Orange-Bioinformatics add-on to the latest version.

Comment: Done. Thanks. Worked perfectly.